# Vagrant Variable VVV Site Wizard - WP site not working

Tags: wordpress, vagrant, virtual-machine, vvv-wordpress

Hi I have setup a Vagrant box with Wordpress installed using VVV (https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV) on my MAC.
This all works fine I can see my Wordpress site @ local.wordpress.dev etc..

I have then used Variable VVV from here https://github.com/bradp/vv to create another separate WP install.

Have followed the instructions from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0MdS1VLvHI and here: https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-wordpress-dev-sites-vagrant-variable-vv/ and got same message as below "New VVV Site Setup: Done! But when I goto the URL nothing appears and says page is not working.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I figured out answer.
Apologies, I should of first asked/found question on the github repo's issues as that is likely where common questions/answers will be.

I added the URL to the vvv-hosts file in the main www directory then I did a

```
sudo vagrant reload
```